# Why am I getting an exception raised from Spring.NET on the call to ContextRegistry.GetContext()?

Tags: c#, wpf, spring.net

*Even though the solution is so obvious I should have never have posted this, I'm leaving it up as a reminder and a useful point of reference to others.*

I've got the following in my app.config file:

```xml
<sectionGroup name="spring">
  <section name="context" type="Spring.Context.Support.ContextHandler, Spring.Core"/>
  <section name="objects" type="Spring.Context.Support.DefaultSectionHandler, Spring.Core" />
</sectionGroup>
```

Followed by:

```xml
<spring>
  <context>
    <resource uri="config://spring/objects"/>
  </context>
  <objects xmlns="http://www.springframework.net">
    <object name="mediaLibrary" type="AlbumLibraryWPF.AlbumLibrary, AlbumLibraryWPF"/>
  </objects>
</spring>
```

Then in my app I've got:

```cs
using Spring.Context;
using Spring.Context.Support;

public partial class AlbumChecker : Window
{
    private DataTable dataTable;

    private Library library;
    private Thread libraryThread;

    public AlbumChecker()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        CreateToolTips();

        IApplicationContext ctx = ContextRegistry.GetContext();
        library = (Library)ctx.GetObject("mediaLibrary");

        // Other initialisation
    }

    // Other code
}
```

It all compiles quite nicely, however, I'm getting an exception raised on the call to GetContext():

```
Error creating context 'spring.root': Could not load type from string value
'AlbumLibraryWPF.AlbumLibrary, AlbumLibraryWPF'.
```

I've checked the Spring.NET documentation and can't see what I'm doing wrong - but I clearly have got something wrong, otherwise it wouldn't raise the exception!

`AlbumLibraryWPF` is the namespace and `AlbumLibraryWPF.AlbumLibrary` is the fully qualified name of the class I want to instantiate. I'm guessing that it's this I've got wrong, but can't see how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I feel such a fool.

It was because I'd failed to copy the AlbumLibrary.dll to the correct output directory. That meant that Spring couldn't find it - even after I'd fixed the assembly name problem Kent highlighted.

Comment: I had this exact same problem because my project outputs were pointing to different locations. Changing the projects to output the dll's to the same directory fixed everything for me

Answer (score 1):

The name after the comma should be the assembly name, which is not necessarily the same as the namespace name.

Comment: Almost - it was because I'd forgotten to copy the AlbumLibrary dll to the correct output directory.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error because by mistake there was a typo [!*2] in app.config file. Once I took that out , error went away. some thing like this

```
<context>
  <!--<resource uri="~//Aspects.xml"/>-->
  <!--<resource uri="~//Dao.xml"/>-->
  <!--<resource uri="~//Spring.xml"/>-->
  <resource uri="file://Spring.xml"/>
  <resource uri="file://Dao.xml"/>
</context>
```

!*2

Answer (score 0):

You should use tha `id` attribute instead of `name`:

```
<object id="mediaLibrary" type="AlbumLibraryWPF.AlbumLibrary, AlbumLibraryWPF"/>
```

Also it should be `config://spring/objects` instead of `config://spring/obects`.

You need to double check that you have a type called `AlbumLibrary` in `AlbumLibraryWPF` namespace defined in `AlbumLibraryWPF` assembly.

Comment: Nope - id still causes the exception to be thrown

Comment: The second was a typo - I tried cut and paste of the code, but Firefox claimed I needed a plugin to be able to see the content - so I typed it out again.

Answer (score -1):

You can try change the type. The type="AlbumLibraryWPF.AlbumLibrary, AlbumLibraryWPF", first parameter means NameSpace and the second parameter (behind the dot) means Solution Name.

- "AlbumLibraryWPF.AlbumLibrary" = NameSapce name
- "AlbumLibraryWPF" = solution name

Comment: It's not the solution name, but the assembly name, please correct your answer.

Comment: `type="namespace.type, assembly"`

Comment: While I appreciate the effort - I solved the problem 2 1/2 years ago. See my answer with the acceptance tick ;)

Answer (score -1):

1. Open VS2012 or VS2010 with Administrator Permissions
2. Config: type="namespace.type, assembly"

Then try running your solution again.